# Generate a tooltip in Tooltipster based on the contents of the element

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip, tooltipster

I'm using a [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster) library to generate tooltip and used their simple [AJAX-custom-function](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#ajax) example as a basis. I need to modify that though so instead of querying a static "http://example.com/ajax.php" as seen in their example it would instead get "http://example.com/ajax.php?id=contents_of_the_element_being_clicked". So for example, if I have a `<span>textbook</span>` in my HTML, the contents link for the popup would be "http://example.com/ajax.php?id=textbook".

I've successfully repurposed the example to activate on every `<span>`, what I cannot do is understand how to bring the innerHTML contents of that `<span>`.

So all I'm looking for is that one line that populates a variable with the element's contents which I can later append to a $.get ... function(data) request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use the `html()` function from `jquery` to extract the inner html. Furthermore, you can use `param()` to encode the extracted html.

```
var param = "?" + $.param({ id: origin.html() });
```

Full example (working with `Tooltipster 3.3.0` and `jQuery 1.10`):

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({    
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        var param = "?" + $.param({ id: origin.html() });       
        if (origin.data('loaded') !== true) {
            $.get('example.com/ajax.php' + param, function(data) {
                origin.data('loaded', true);
                origin.tooltipster('content', data.id);
                continueTooltip();
            });            
        }
        else {
            continueTooltip();        
        }
    }
});
```

`Tooltipster Version 4`:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({    
    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {
        var $origin = $(helper.origin);
        var param = "?" + $.param({ id: $origin.html() });       
        if ($origin.data('loaded') !== true) {
            $.get('example.com/ajax.php' + param, function(data) {
                instance.content(data.id);
                $origin.data('loaded', true);
            });            
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="tooltip" title="This is my span's tooltip message!">Some text test</span>
```

Comment: Just copypasting the example I get TypeError: origin.html is not a function. (In 'origin.html()', 'origin.html' is undefined)

Comment: It contains the content of the `span`: here `Some text test`. This function is not part of Tooltipster, it is implemented in the jquery library. `param` contains the `id` parameter your query. Finally, you have to adapt the query url, this is my example from `jsfiddle`.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Tooltipster? I used an older one (3.3.0) - it's different with 4.0. Here, you have to adapt the example from the tooltipster homepage.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that. However I get that error that I provided above (comment just edited) and it doesn't seem to be related to either the contents of the span element or the contents of the param variable. The message I get again is "TypeError: origin.html is not a function. (In 'origin.html()', 'origin.html' is undefined)" so it doesn't seem to be related to Tooltipster.

Comment: I use the latest version of Tooltipster.

Comment: In this [github issue](https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/566) the migration from `Version 3` to `Version 4` is described. You have to use `functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {...`,  `$(helper.origin).html()` and `continueTooltip();` is replaced with `return true;`. The principle remains the same.

Comment: Yes, it worked. If you could edit the answer I'll accept it. Basically the example from Tooltipster's website remains all intact (for my use case), the only thing needing to be added is var param = $.param({ id: $(helper.origin).html() }); and you also need to append the get string so it looks like $.get('http://example.com/ajax.php' + param, function(data). All the rest remains unchanged from the example.

Comment: Added the modified example as second variant.